# non-interactive login in Powershell for Key Vault

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to do a certificate-based non-auth script in powershell to upload files to my KeyVault.

Currently this is the program that I have:

```
$tenantId = "xxx"
$appId = "xxx"
$certificateThumbprint = "xxx"
Connect-AzAccount -ApplicationId $appId -Tenant $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $certificateThumbprint
```

However, when I login to my keyvault I don't see a tenant id or an app id. All I see is a subscription ID and a Directory ID

Therefore I'm getting the following error:

```
Connect-AzAccount : No certificate was found in the certificate store with thumbprint xxxx
At C:\Users\alchave\OneDrive - Microsoft\Documents\PowerShellScripts\testing.ps1:10 char:1
+ Connect-AzAccount -ApplicationId $tenantId -Tenant $appId -Certificat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

Where can I get the tenant Id and the app Id from KeyVault in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

you dont really login to key vault (you login to azure), you need a service principal to login silently with powershell, you are missing a certificate you would use to login, you need to grant your service principal right over key vault to be able to interact with. All of this is easily searchable on the web. For the login, however, the links are specified below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-3.3.0#certificate-based-authentication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-3.3.0#certificate-based-authentication